# How to connect VPN clients through NAT to SQL Server

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, nat

We have 2 servers, 1 Windows Server 2019 Standard used as a VPN Server, 1 Windows Server 2012 R2 with SQL Server on it.

These 2 are connected by an internal network, 10.1.1.0/24 address range, VPN server is 10.1.1.5, SQL server is 10.1.1.1

The VPN server is working, and when clients connect they receive an address in the 192.168.42.0/24 range.

For example, one client is 192.168.42.3, and the VPN server is 192.168.42.1 from the client point of view. I can ping the VPN server, and connect to its resources.

How do I setup so that the clients can connect to the SQL server, through a NAT, static route or other means, so that the clients can connect to the SQL server using 192.168.42.X, and the SQL server only ever sees 10.1.1.5, which is the internal IP of the VPN server.

[Picture of network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6PqJ.png)

Is this even possible?